# Return values that have first three characters are letters

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a way to only return rows that have the first 3 values are alphabetic.
   Something like

```
       Select GUITAR_DESC
       From Prod.INVENTOR
       WHERE LEFT(GUITAR_DESC,3)LIKE('[A-Z]%'
```

Should return

```
        FEN314
        GIB452
```

This doesn't work.
   Currently is there anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: you may also use [fn:matches](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrfnmat.html)

Comment: can you give me an example? Not really sure what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many SQL engines support range of letters in `LIKE` clause, so you could be using it like this:

```
Select GUITAR_DESC
From Prod.INVENTOR
WHERE GUITAR_DESC LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%'
```

Unfortunately it seems that DB2 does not support this option. As a workaround you can use `substr` function and `BETWEEN` operator like this:

```
Select GUITAR_DESC
From Prod.INVENTOR
WHERE (substr(GUITAR_DESC,1,1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z') AND
      (substr(GUITAR_DESC,2,1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z') AND
      (substr(GUITAR_DESC,3,1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z')
```

Comment: hmm this didn't work. Does it matter if the Guitar_Desc is a CHAR Type?

Comment: @Sewder You are right, it seems DB2 has some options that are not supported. I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fairly new version of DB2 (tested on 10.1 for z/OS, and 9.7 Linux/Unix/Windows), you can use regex with Xquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table A
WHERE
    XMLCAST(
        XMLQUERY('fn:matches($col, "^[A-Z]")' passing A.your_column AS "col")
    AS INTEGER) = 1
```